# Search or filter JTable on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

How can I perform a search in `JTable`?

My CSV file contains:

> stdid    001
>   stdname  monish
>   dob      03/5/1789

And similar records for the rest of the file. I am able to bind using CSV Parser and get data into `JTable`. I want to perform a search on it the table using input from a `JTextField`. How  can I perform this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`RowFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html)/[`RowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html). You can read more at [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) from the [How to use Tables tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

You can can also see a working example in the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20325722/2587435).

[image]

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20325937/2587435) also provides a solution for case-insensitive filtering, if you're interested in that functionality