# How to accept both uppercase and lowercase letters when using filter search in jTable?

Tags: java, search, filter, jtable

I'm done with my filter searching and converting row index to model. Now my problem is how to accept both uppercase and lowercase letters when searching?

P.S. I am using search for my JTable

```
private void filter(String query) 
{
     DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
     TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sort = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
     jTable1.setRowSorter(sort);       
     sort.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));
 }

private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
{                                        
     int[] selection = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
 selection[i] = jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(selection[i]);   
    String query = jTextField1.getText();      
    filter(query); }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked into ways to ignore case using regular expressions (maybe a quick Google)? Also I'd use a DocumentListener over KeyListener

Comment: I've been searching through google but what I've seen is that it only returns true or false.

Comment: how do i apply it into my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question seems as this here: [How can I perform a case-insensitive filter on a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325722/how-can-i-perform-a-case-insensitive-filter-on-a-jtable)
and has been already answered.
Meziano

Comment: this is the answer that I'm looking for! Thanks you! appreciate it :)