# Search in SQL table through JTextField key released with both UPPERCASE or LOWERCASE

Tags: java, sql, swing

I want to search customer name in SQL table through JTextField key released in NetBeans.

Here is my code of JTextField key released :

```
DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel(); 
String search = jTextField1.getText(); 
TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new  TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);

jTable1.setRowSorter(tr);
tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search));
```

For example, If I want to find a customer name `" RoNaldo "` when I write starting word like that `" ronaldo "` then it's not working. Actually when writing the same word like that `" RoNaldo "` then it would be shown in the table. So, please provide me the right code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this,

```
DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new  TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);

String search = jTextField1.getText().toLowerCase();
if (search.trim().length() == 0) {
      tr.setRowFilter(null);
   } else {
      tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + search));
 }
```

Comment: Did you put that in jTextField1 key released event?

Comment: YES, BUT IT'S NOT SEARCHING ANY THING

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Esto le ayudará:
[How can I perform a case-insensitive filter on a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325722/how-can-i-perform-a-case-insensitive-filter-on-a-jtable)

Pero sin mas nada, la expresión regular que debe usar es `"(?i)"+search` :

```
tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + search));
```

Comment: Amigo, en el link que le proporcioné, las dos respuestas propuestas puede implementar. La segunda respuesta es una buena opción también.

Comment: pero lo comprobé en jtext keyreleased ... no está buscando nada

Answer (score 0):

Besides a case-insensitive search, also sorting on that column should be case-insensitive ideally.

```
final int nameColumn = 1;
tr.setComparator(nameColumn, (lhs, rhs) -> ((String)lhs).compareToIgnoreCase((String) rhs));
```

The above assumes the column to be 1, adapt it to the correct one.

Comment: I checked this code in  JTextField key released but it's not working ... please provide me complete code